# Insert PHP Regex Exploded Array Into MySQL Table

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli, foreach

I have an array that I exploded by Regex, here is a part of the array named $data;

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(77) "Achnanthes brevipes C.Agardh, Syst. Alg.: 1 (1824). / Küçük sucıncığı."
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "Achnanthes"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "brevipes"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "C.Agardh"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(21) "Syst. Alg.: 1 (1824)."
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "Küçük sucıncığı"
  }
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(89) "Achnanthes cocconeiformis Mann, U.S. Nat. Mus., Bull. 6: 182 (1925). / Top sucıncığı."
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "Achnanthes"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "cocconeiformis"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Mann"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(36) "U.S. Nat. Mus., Bull. 6: 182 (1925)."
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "Top sucıncığı"
  }
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(108) "Achnanthes gibberula Grunow, Kongl. Svenska Vetensk.-Akad. Handl. 17(2): 121 (1880). / Kambur sucıncığı."
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "Achnanthes"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "gibberula"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Grunow"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(55) "Kongl. Svenska Vetensk.-Akad. Handl. 17(2): 121 (1880)."
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(20) "Kambur sucıncığı"
  }
}
```

and many more..

my regex is:

```
$turRegex = '/^([^\s]+)[\s]([^\s]+)[\s]([^\s]+)[,][\s]([A-Za-z].+)[\s][\/][\s](.+)[.]/m';
```

my foreach loop:

```
foreach ($data as $data) {


    if (!empty(preg_match_all($turRegex, $data, $matches))) {

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($matches);
        echo "</pre>";

    }
}
```

My table name is "algeaSpecies" and columns are; "id","genusName","speciesEpiteth","author", "publication","TurkishName"

I want to insert this to genusName;

```
[1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "Achnanthes"
```

this to speciesEpiteth;

```
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "brevipes"
  }
```

and others...

[image: here is a final image]

I'm using MySQLi

Thank you

Comment: `$turRegex` could be reduced to `~^(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+),\s([a-z].+)\s/\s(.+)\.~mi`

Answer (score 0):

First I noticed you used `$data` both as array and item in your loop.

In the following code, I assumed that you don't want the first index (the query wasn't clear).

Also, replace the DB connection credentials.

```
$con = new mysqli('db_host', 'username', 'password', 'db_name');
$boundArray = array_fill(0, 5, null);
$query = "INSERT INTO `algeaSpecies` (`genusName`, `speciesEpiteth`, `author`, `publication`, `TurkishName`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", ...$boundArray);


foreach ($data as $item) {
    $i = -1;
    foreach ($item as $index) {
        if ($i === -1) {
            $i++;
            continue;
        }
        $boundArray[$i++] = $index[0];
    }
    $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
$con->close();
```

Comment: I really didn't understand

Comment: Which part? Line 1 is the connection to the DB, line 2 is an array to bound to the prepared statement with default values, line 3 -5 are database preparation. The logic happens in the loop: get each index and fill the boundArray with it's value, then execute the prepared statement.

Comment: Have you tested that it works? I am somewhat sceptical about that execute in the loop. You splat the array and I am not sure if that retains the reference.

Comment: I've tested it based on the data structure you've provided. I've split the $data 2 times to get to the data (based on the data structure you've provided). If you need $index and $item retain the references you could add & before them ($data as &$item) but I'm not sure why you want that?